# Regex for currency in Java string.replaceAll() (not php, not javascript)

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to get prices from a text **in Java**, I'm usign this regex but **I can't get rid of 113**:

```
String str="jañlskd f añlksdj fñlaks: 19,05€ | jfañlskdjf: 22€ jañlsdkf dkjfls 113: 15€ jñalkdf dk añldf: añlkdsj fdlkf dlkfajs 19,05€ buy";
str.replaceAll("[^0-9+€|^0-9+,0-9+€|^ ]","");
```

Result is:

19,05€ |  22€   **113** 15€       19,05€

**I want to dismiss numbers with no € at the end too.**

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: This may work with a lookahead `\d+(?:,\d+)?(?=€)` [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/vM2bH9)

Comment: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )  if I try with 0-9 instead does nothing at all, returns same string

Comment: `\d+` = `[0-9]+`, I'm not a Java developer ^^

Comment: @DavidGarcia if you're using Java try `\\d+(?:,\\d+)?(?=€)` instead. Java needs an extra backslash for regex backslashes

Comment: @David Garcia If you see something like that, it means you didn't double your backslashes

Comment: String priceAux = new String("jañlskd f añlksdj fñlaks: 19,05€ | jfañlskdjf: 22€ jañlsdkf dkjfls 113: 15€ jñalkdf dk añldf: añlkdsj fdlkf dlkfajs 19,05€ buy"); priceAux.replaceAll("\\d+(?:,\\d+)?(?=€)","") ->>Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: @DavidGarcia Just a question, do you want to get ride from all the prices and the numbers like 113 too ?

Comment: Nop, just get ride of anything is not a number plus € simbol at the end. F.ex.: I want to keep 2€ 2,2€ 2.2€ 342€ 0,34€ etc.

Comment: @DavidGarcia you will make it complexer to **not** match something, match all the prices and concatenate it with a function.

Comment: I have to do it in a negative way to use replaceAll(regex,"")

Comment: Unless this is for school you aren't forced to do it that way, I'm just wondering why people take the hardway while there is a more secure and reliable and short/easy way ?

Answer (score 0):

The full answer to this question is:

1. Don't use replaceAll (is more complicated in this case).
2. Use a matcher to find positive matches.

Example:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)?(?=€)");
Matcher m=p.matcher(nodeValue);
String res=new String();
while (m.find()) {
    res+=m.group()+" ";
}
String prices=res.split(" ");
```

Thanks to all (specially HamZa).